# How to rewrite an MDX statement so will be based on LastNonEmpty Measures (representing versions over time)

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

The MDX conditionally decides between two measures based on half year choosen

### AS-IS:

The [Conditional Forecast Cost] is generated by the following SCOPE-Statements based on measures called "Cost" and "Forecast Cost".

```
MEASURES.[Conditional Forecast Cost] = [Measures].[Forecast Cost]
SCOPE([DIM Date].[Half Year].&[1])
    MEASURES.[Conditional Forecast Cost] = [Measures].[Cost];
END SCOPE;
```

If the first half year is choosen the Measure "Cost" is applied.
For the second half year the Measure "Forecast Cost" is applied.

Additional information:
The DIM Date Dimension has a hierachie just with "YEAR-Month" (of course some additional Attributes).

### TO-BE:

The MDX query should consider that [Forecast Cost] & [Cost] are LastNonEmpty.
The LastNonEmpty represents most recent version of the Measure.
The Versioning is basically a date dimension called "DIM Date Version".